# To find out the last used database object?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

Is there any way to find out when one specific table/view/M-view is used last time. i.e. when one specific object is used in any SELECT statement.

Comment: a non-scientific answer, but go look at SELECT SQL_TEXT FROM V$SQL
order by last_load_time desc;

Answer (score 0):

you can use ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS  views to get DML on a table.

For an object recently used time in Select Statement:-
    SQL> select count(*) from scott.emp;

```
COUNT(*)
----------
14

SQL> select sql_id,sql_text ,LAST_ACTIVE_TIME from v$sql where lower(sql_text) like '%scott.emp%' and  lower(sql_text) not in ('select sql_id,sql_text ,LAST_ACTIVE_TIME from v$sql%');

SQL_ID        SQL_TEXT                                         LAST_ACTIVE_TIME
------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------
abj9tmfcs15bm select count(*) from scott.emp                               27-JUL-18
```

Best way to check would be generate a AWR report for time frame you want to check and open it in a browser , CTRL + F and search for table name.  If you see table name in search then your table was used during that period.

Comment: Hi I am trying to execute the above query but giving the error so is it possible to give with the real time example?